# Intercept file read/write in iOS

Tags: ios

Is it possible to intercept file read/write of other apps in iOS?
What I want to do is encrypt files automatically when an app writes to filesystem but the behavior changes depending on the app.
For example, there are apps A and B (A and B is not my own app). When A is writing to a file encrypt the file but when B is writing to a file I do not encrypt the file.

As security is considered in iOS I know that I can not do this without users permission but the question is when the user permits it if its possible to create/install such app.

I'm from windows world and in windows we can make filesystem filter driver to do this but I think iOS never permits to install such driver.
Is there any other option?

Comment: If cydia is an option, than anything is possible. If not, you're screwed...

Comment: I can't imagine Apple allowing apps like this onto the app store at this point, with their restrictions on app sandboxing.

Comment: I believe, if an iOS device has a passcode set then files are already being encrypted.  See http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf for details

Comment: Yea. I know about this. The point is that the encryption behavior must be different depending on apps.